# I modified my htaccess file but not sure if it's correct

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to add the "www" infront of my domain, which I have done but not sure if it was added properly because I removed some of the code from the original `.htaccess` file which came with the open source script.

**Original `.htaccess` file:**

```bash
# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# disabel access to logs/template files
<Files ~ "\.(log|tpl)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploaded [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

**Current `.htaccess` file:**

```bash
# secures htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# disable access to logs/template files
<Files ~ "\.(log|tpl)$">
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</files>

# Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websitename.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websitename.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploaded [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: If you are asking if you should have removed the other code from the original file, then I would say no, as that was there for a reason (for your open-source script). Take the last three lines from the original file, and add them to the end of the current one.

Comment: I just want to add www infront of my domain, is there a better way to add that to the original code, if so please can you show me? Thank you

Comment: Your code to do that is fine. Just add `$` after `^websitename.com` to ensure the regular expression closes properly.

Comment: Hi Mike, I updated my htaccess code, please review and let me know if it looks good or not. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the second `RewriteEngine on` and then it's fine.

Comment: Ok done. Thanks for saving the day, Mike. Have a good night/day.